# Has WebDriver.switchTo().activeElement() stopped working on Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-iedriver

Whenever I call `WebDriver.switchTo().activeElement()` to get the focused `WebElement` during a test running on `IE`, I receive the error :

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.

though the browser is still running. I recall that this used to work, but I'm not sure if it's something I've broken in my test setup or if it's an actual Selenium defect. Has anyone else had similar issues?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Selenium 3.0? Then Yes. It is currently using a POST request instead of a GET request. There is an open bug on it, but doesn't look like it's been actively looked at.

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2751

Comment: I'm not, still on 2.53, is it broken on that too?